# Hidding a form with onBlur but this have a conflict with submit button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to hide the form with the onBlur event, but when I try to click the submit button the onSubmit function doesn't get triggered

I want to hide it after send the form or when the user leaves the div that wraps the form.

https://codesandbox.io/s/rrz10y2mnp

`index.js`

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

`test.ts`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Test extends Component {
  state = {
    showing: false
  };

  showInput = () => {
    this.setState({ showing: false });
  };

  addNew = () => {
    this.setState({ showing: true });
  };

  sendForm = evt => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    console.log("clicked");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {!this.state.showing ? (
          <button onClick={this.addNew}>Add a new</button>
        ) : (
          <div onBlur={this.showInput} tabIndex="1">
            <form onSubmit={this.sendForm}>
              <input autoFocus={true} type="text" />
              <button type="submit">PUSH</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to hide the form until after doing `sendForm` why not just do the hiding at the end of the `sendForm` function?

Comment: I will create a lot of cards with the same form, that's why I want to hide it with the onBlur event

Comment: That doesn't prevent you from hiding the form within `sendForm` though, If it does please explain

Comment: The problem is when I try to use the submit button, the onBlur event triggers without execute the onSubmit function

Answer (score 2):

Hide form in the sendForm function that you have. Then it should be fine. If there is some async function  in sendForm you can hideForm when promise gets resolved and till then disable input.

Comment: I will have a lot of cards with the same form, I want to hide when the user click outside the box or when the user submit the form

Comment: If the user clicks outside form will simply be hidden without data submission right? And on submit it will be hidden.

Comment: The problem is when I try to use the submit button, the onBlur event triggers without execute the onSubmit function

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your calling `setState` before the form submits. You could use some async code to fix this issue. Here's a rudimentary example simply using `setTimeout` and waiting 100 milliseconds. There are better ways to do this and many reasons why you shouldn't.

```
   waitToSetState = () => {
     setTimeout(() => {
       this.setState({ showing: false });
     }, 100);
   };
```

...

```
   <div onBlur={this.waitToSetState} tabIndex="1">
     <form onSubmit={this.sendForm}>
       <input autoFocus={true} type="text" />
       <button type="submit">PUSH</button>
     </form>
   </div>
```